# Pytest parametrize inside test class

Tags: pytest

I have the following code where I am trying to generate tests with some testdata.

```
class Test_ABC(BaseTestCase):
    testdata = [
                (7,  'Jan', 2018, 'Jul', 2018),
                (8,  'Jan', 2018, 'Aug', 2018),
                (18, 'Jan', 2017, 'Jun', 2018),
                (36, 'Jan', 2015, 'Dec', 2017),
                (48, 'Jan', 2014, 'Dec', 2017),
               ]

    @pytest.mark.parametrize("a, b, c, d", testdata)
    def test_abc(self, a, b, c, d):
        print (a, b, c, d)
```

Snipper from BaseTestCase:

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures('init_browser')
class BaseTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(BaseTestCase, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

When I use pytest to execute this script, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: test_abc() missing 5 required positional arguments: 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'
C:\Python3\lib\unittest\case.py:605: TypeError
```

This seems to be working if I dont inherit BaseTestCase in my test class 'Test_ABC'.

Any idea what I'm missing here in my test case or in BaseTestCase?

Comment: [Parametrization won't work with `unittest` classes](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/unittest.html#pytest-features-in-unittest-testcase-subclasses).

Answer (score 2):

You don't have enough arguments in param(As it stated in error). Try this:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("a, b, c, d, e", testdata)
def test_abc(self, a, b, c, d, e):
    print (a, b, c, d)  # without year
```

And also pytest not seek tests in classes with `__init__` constructor. Remove it and replace `unittest.TestCase` with `object`